# JavaScript typeof undefined in class

Tags: javascript, class, pixi.js

When I make a class:

```
class DialogueChoice
{
    constructor(text, resultFunc) //dialogue line text, function to call when selected
    {
        this.integer = 25;
        ...
    }
    test()
    {
        console.log(typeof(this.integer))
    }
}
```

I get undefined as the type instead of a number when calling test(). Why is this? what am I missing? It happens for the other members as well. As far as I can tell the class is losing all it's members after the constructor? Trying to print the value results in undefined as well. The issue only occurs when the func is called through pixijs event system. Calling from the main body of the script is fine.

Comment: Without knowing the context of the call it’s hard to help. Maybe calling it from an event handler and haven’t grokked `this` yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How do you use your class, because to me it seems to work as expected?

```js
class DialogueChoice
{
    constructor(text, resultFunc) //dialogue line text, function to call when selected
    {
        this.integer = 25;
    }
    test()
    {
        console.log(typeof(this.integer))
    }
}

var dc = new DialogueChoice();
dc.test();
```

When you pass the `test` method to another function that then calls it, you have to make sure to bind it to the original object that it is attached to. Otherwise the context for that method will be the global object `window`. Something like this:

```
someOtherFunction(dc.test.bind(dc));
```

Alternatively you can wrap it in another function:

```
someOtherFunction(() => dc.test());
```

Comment: sorry, I wasn't clear enough in the question, thought I fixed it but didn't

Comment: final line works for me, can you explain what it actually does and why it changes anything? shouldn't this.integer still point to this.integer regardless of how I pass the function ref?

Comment: Where `this` is pointing to depends on how a method is called. When you call a method that is attached to an object like this `object.fn()` the interpreter sets the `this` context to be the `object` itself. But when you **pass** the method by itself to some other function that then calls the method, the original `this` context is lost and the default context `window` is used instead. So by wrapping the method call in another function you make sure that the original context is used.

Comment: weird, I assumed `this` when used on a class' member function would always point to the object. thanks for your help

Comment: In the end the class' instance is just a simple object with a function attached. It doesn't matter how it was created - the same rules for `this` still apply.

Comment: @GamingGecko Search for “js this late binding” or similar to start getting a broader picture.